# SQL Date to Text

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am running the below query and would like to convert the column 'JVDATE' into just showing the month.

Query:

```
SELECT 
   FISCALYEAR, JVDATE, ACCOUNTNUMBER, ACCOUNTDESCRIPTION, 
   CATEGORY, POSTINGTYPE, AUDITTRAIL, 
   ORIGDOCNUMBER, ORIGDEBIT, ORIGCREDIT, ORIGNETAMOUNT
FROM 
   SRVS.dbo.vw_GLTrialBalancev2010
```

When I run the query I get .....

[image]

What is the easiest way to do this?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you maybe want [`DATENAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx)?

```
SELECT ..., DATENAME(Month,JVDate) as Month,....
```

(Or, if you want it as a numeric value, as per @Amit's answer, I'd usually go with the [`DATEPART`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) function, since it applies to all component parts rather than having to find specific functions for each component)